# How to verify a specific expected method in easymock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

How can I use Easymock.verify(mockedObject); to check only a specific expected method call on that mocked object instead of checking all the expected methods.

In another words how can I verify the call of specific method rather than all of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly set the number of calls expected of the methods that you do not want to check to `.anyTimes()`

```
expect(mymock.unwantedMethod()).andReturn("something).anyTimes()
```

or make it a stub implementation:

```
expect(mymock.unwantedMethod()).andStubReturn("something)
```

This way only the expected method call will be validated.